# Do sidebands corresponds to real photons at that frequency?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons

Say I have a carrier laser (optical) frequency $\omega_c$: $E=E_0 e^{i\omega_c t}$.

I propagate it through an electro-optical modulator that modulates the phase by $\beta \sin\Omega t$: $E = E_0 e^{i\omega_c t + i\beta \sin(\Omega t)}$.

If $\beta \ll 1$, the field can be expanded into:

$$ E \propto e^{i\omega_c t} + e^{i(\omega_c+\Omega) t} + e^{i(\omega_c-\Omega) t} , $$

where the new $\omega_c\pm\Omega$ are the *sidebands.*

**Question**:

The laser emits photons at energy $\hbar\omega_c$.  After the modulation, are there actually photons at energies $\hbar(\omega_c\pm\Omega)$?

Comment: If you put the beam into a spectrometer what would you see? Are those not real photons?

Comment: What else could they possibly be?

Comment: I am puzzled by second-harmonic generation devices needing a non-linear effect to generate photons of a different frequency from the incident one. An EOM since to be able to do this too easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I believe the answer to the question in the title is yes, they are real photons. As Jon Custer mentioned, in a spectrometer there would be photons detected at the frequencies $\omega_c \pm \Omega$. Moreover, if you make the EOM modulation depth very strong, e.g. $\beta = 2.405 =$ a root of first Bessel function, you can completely extinguish the carrier: there are no photons of $\omega_c$ left.

The distinction between creating sidebands and so-called 'non-linear effects' (eg. second-harmonic generation in optics) I would explain as follows.

**High-harmonic generation (HHG)**

The products of HHG are photons which have a large energy mismatch compared to the initial photons. Therefore, you need a large power (strong non-linearity) to create them. Similarly, in an electrical circuit, you can create harmonics using a mixer, a highly non-linear element.

**Sidebands**

The products of creating sidebands usually have very similar energies as the initial photons, essentially no energy has to be added or taken away from the initial photons. Therefore a 'small' non-linearity is enough to prepare them. The EOM *does* act as a non-linear element, the non-linearity given by the response of a polarising beam splitter on a turning polarisation, which is sinusoidal, that is, non-linear. (You can create sidebands with an EOM operating on the linear slope the sine and then you only get sidebands at $\pm\Omega$ but no higher harmonics than that.) Similarly, in an electrical circuit you can simply have the input voltage of a voltage-controlled oscillator (VCO) oscillate and you will get some sidebands at $n\Omega$. But the bandwidth of this input voltage is not usually enough to create multiples of the carrier frequency $\omega_c$.